# c# - How to force closing of background worker that run it own threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, appdomain

I have wpf application, lets call it `A-app`. `A-app` runs asyncronic `B-method` with a background worker. That `B-method` is located at a different project, and it creates few threads for the `B-method` init part.

User can ask to run the `B-method` and can ask to cancel the run and restart.
The problem is that if it is cancelled in the init time, the background worker, which run the `B-method` is cancelled, but the threads are not.
Restarting creates more thread that cannot work at the same time as the threads from previous run, and it couse some bugs.

Threads method is mostly waiting.

How can I stop the `B-method` and also cancel the threads it created?

Is a different AppDomain could help in any way? (and than close the whole app domain?) If yes, that how should it be done?
Is there a better way?

**More details:**

- The B-method runs tests on some devices (could be many). the init of the method is connecting to devices - i/o - so most time is spend on waiting (this is the reason we decided to make the connection init parallel).tring to connect to the same device from 2 different threads may cause problems.

Comment: Yes AppDomain is probably best. How to unload one has been asked many times (see the colum  on the right here)

Comment: The concepts of AppDomain and threads are orthogonal. Unloading an AppDomain is not a good way to Cancel a worker.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't create Threads at all but use the TaskScheduler and work with the Parallel Task Library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

The TaskScheduler himself is a wrapper for the ThreadPool, which handles the Threads. It even does stuf like WorkStealing, Task Inling etc.

At best you start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997402%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Another approach is to start Tasks with a CancalletionToken, which enables you to cancel Tasks. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537607%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Edit: Okey, no TPL, Blocking Threads. This leaves basically only the Thread.Abort.
This is messy, but there is no perfect world, so think about the Form as Application A, and ClassB is Application B:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Thread _threadA;
    Thread _threadB;
    Thread _threadC;

    ClassB b1 = new ClassB();
    ClassB b2 = new ClassB();
    ClassB b3 = new ClassB();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _threadA = new Thread(() => b1.DoSomeWork("A"));
        _threadB = new Thread(() => b2.DoSomeWork("B"));
        _threadC = new Thread(() => b3.DoSomeWork("C"));
    }

    private void btnStartWork_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _threadA.Start();
        _threadB.Start();
        _threadC.Start();
    }

    private void btnStopThreadA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AbortThreadA();
    }

    private void btnStopThreadB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AbortThreadB();
    }

    private void btnStopThreadC_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AbortThreadC();
    }

    private void AbortThreadA()
    {
        _threadA.Abort();
    }

    private void AbortThreadB()
    {
        _threadB.Abort();
    }

    private void AbortThreadC()
    {
        _threadC.Abort();
    }

    private void btnStopAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AbortThreadA();
        AbortThreadB();
        AbortThreadC();
    }
}



class ClassB
{
    public void DoSomeWork(string threadIdentifier)
    {
        try
        { 
            string preWorkString = "Work work Okeydokey. Thread: " + threadIdentifier;
            string postWorkString = "Job's Done. Thread: " + threadIdentifier;

            while (true)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(preWorkString);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(postWorkString);
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Thread aborted. Thread: " + threadIdentifier);
            Thread.ResetAbort();
        }
    }
}
```

ResetAbort is needed, otherwise the Error gets bubbled.

Is that a possible solution?

Comment: Since working with old environment, i can't upgrade .Net version, so this is not an option (Tasks are from .Net 4, i think). Just out of curiosity, is there a better way to cancel tasks than threads? It is just a wrapper, and the thread is mostly on wait state.

Comment: The TaskScheduler is as said just a Wrapper for the ThreadPool. You can let the ThreadPool handle the Threads. You basically create a amount of Threads at the Start and let the Pool do the handling between it. I'd say creating new Threads directly is almost never a good idea.

Comment: I understand that, still, the question is about cancellation. What would be different of using the pool instead of directly start a thread? How the cancellation is different?

Comment: Edited my post for another solution

Answer (score 0):

Do you own B-method (ie can you change it?)

I'm assuming B-method is not intrinsically cancellable, and you are just cancelling the background worker that calls it in module A?

B-method needs to be changed to either be cancellable, or re-entrant. By re-entrant I mean that it will allow multiple calls to itself, and will re-use any existing init sequence that is already in progress.

Comment: B-method is a start point to a long term tests actions (it calles many other methods, most time in here is also I/O and wait)